# Landscape syncing mirror pockets

Tags: 16.04, repository, landscape

So I am giving it a try to Landscape but I am having multiple issues along the way, what I want to attempt top do is to create a local or main repository on my Landscape server, so all the clients when they search and install for a package, they get it through the landscape server and not themselves on the internet.

I have created a distributions

```
# landscape-api create-distribution lala-ubuntu
```

I also created series and pockets that according to the documentation, will hold the actual packages:

```
# landscape-api create-series --pockets release,updates --components main,extras,restricted --architectures i386,amd64,x86_64 --gpg-key secret-key --mirror-uri http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ --mirror-series xenial xenial lala-ubuntu
```

However, the issues occurs once I start the sync mirror process:

```
# landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket release xenial apl-ubuntu
# landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket updates xenial apl-ubuntu
```

I get something like this:

```
{u'activity_status': u'undelivered',  u'children': [{u'activity_status': u'undelivered',
                u'children': [],
                u'completion_time': None,
                u'creation_time': u'2016-12-28T13:52:00Z',
                u'id': 151,
                u'parent_id': 150,
                u'pocket_id': 9,
                u'pocket_name': u'release',
                u'progress': 0,
                u'result_code': None,
                u'result_text': None,
                u'schedule_after_time': None,
                u'schedule_before_time': None,
```

and when I query the ID I get:

```
u'result_text': u"Could not find 'main/binary-x86_64/Packages' within './lists/update-xenial_xenial_InRelease'\r\nThere have been errors!\r\n",   u'schedule_after_time': None,   u'schedule_before_time': None,   u'summary': u"Sync pocket 'release' of series 'xenial' in distribution 'apl-ubuntu'",
```

Anybody has any experience with this or has successfully managed to create a local repo for landscape clients? Any help will be very very appreciated

Documentation I am referring to: https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/ch09.html "repository Management"

Comment: Could you please restructure your question and do a better presentation. Which documentation are you referring to ?

Comment: I now updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're specifying the x86_64 architecture but that is not a valid architecture name. Do this instead:

```
# landscape-api create-series --pockets release,updates --components main,extras,restricted --architectures i386,amd64 --gpg-key secret-key --mirror-uri http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ --mirror-series xenial xenial lala-ubuntu
```

This should work better. Also, consider adding the security pocket if you care for security updates (--pockets release,security,updates).